# Реализация аутентификаци в трех уровневой архитектуре

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, архитектура

Собственно вопрос в теме. Как правильно разделить стандартную *SimpleMembership* аутентификацию.

Я понимаю, что классы - в *DAL*, всякие usermanager - в *BLL*, формы авторизации и контроллеры, которые передают данные в BLL - на уровне представления.

Но вот как сделать(правильно), чтобы контроллер смог получить доступ к классам в *DAL*, если он может иметь доступ только к *BLL*?

Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Причем тут авторизация?

Answer (score 1):

надо унаследовать от UserManager свой класс, тогда в DAL лазить не прийдется. ну и все Entity модели вообще положить в отдельную сборку, чтоб можно было разный DAL юзать, кстати UserStore тоже лучше иметь свой и положить его в DAL.
Вобщем то в DAL должны жить только методы работающие с базой

Answer (score 0):

SimpleMembership? Есть же asp.net identity. Но в любом случае нужно будет делать свою реализацию юзер менеджера.